# Is it possible to open server ports on TUN devices?

Tags: linux, networking, unix, vpn, tunnel

If I make a VPN connection to a server (say myvpn.com; assume this server is not behind any router/firewall) via a TUN device and open a port (say 5555), will someone else be able to connect to me via myvpn.com:5555? If not, is there a tunneling software that does exactly this in a transparent manner? i.e. run **any** TCP/UDP-based server instance behind a router without NAT using another remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the idea correctly, but if you want clients connecting to myvpn.com:5555 actually get connected to your host, you can try SSH port forwarding (-L option):

```
-L 5555:myvpn.com:5555
```

Comment: The proper argument seems to be `ssh -R x.x.x.x:3000:localhost:3000 your.remote.machine`. Thanks anyways. (http://bbrinck.com/post/2318562750/reverse-ssh-tunneling-easier-than-port-forwarding)